# MS ACCESS VBA module Auto number format

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Repoerteq table with a REQ_NUM as ID and another column named "REQ_department".
 REQ_department have defult values such as ""Finance".

I want to make VBA looks at the department and then set a prefix formate for REQ_NUM 
example is department is finance then it would make id as "FIN 000"

the following code is what i manage fo far but it still not working

```
Option Compare Database
Function GetData() As String

   Dim db As Database
   Dim Rrs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim RSQL As String
   Dim RepData As String
   Dim RepDep As String

   'TO open connection to current Access DB
   Set db = CurrentDb()

   'TO create SQL statement and retrieve value from ReportReq table
   RSQL = "select * from ReportReq"

   Set Rrs = db.OpenRecordset(RSQL)

   'Retrieve value if data is found
   If Rrs.EOF = False Then
      RepData = Rrs("REQ_NUM")
      RepDep = Rrs("Req_department")
   Else
      RepData = "Not found"
      RepDep = "Not found"
   End If

     Lrs.Close
   Set Lrs = Nothing

   GetData = RepData

    If ReqDep = "finance" Then
   Range("REQ_NUM") = Format$("FIN", REQ_NUM)

   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your call to the `Format()` function which tries to format a number or date according to the format string. In addition, you're using an undefined variable REQ_NUM.

```
If ReqDep = "finance" Then
    Range("REQ_NUM") = "FIN " & Format$("000", CLng(RepData))
    '                  ^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
End If
```